# Jenkins Groovy scheduled job, get link

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jobs

I'm scheduling my Jenkins jobs using groovy script:

```
def job = hudson.model.Hudson.instance.getJob("job")
def params = new StringParameterValue('PARAMTEST', "somestring")  
def paramsAction = new ParametersAction(params) 
def cause = new hudson.model.Cause.UpstreamCause(currentBuild)
def causeAction = new hudson.model.CauseAction(cause) 
def scheduledJob = hudson.model.Hudson.instance.queue.schedule(job, 0, causeAction, paramsAction)
```

Is there any way to retrieve the actual job link so I can be redirected within the console output to the job page?

Thanks!

Comment: When i Execute above  mentioned groovy script, I'm getting below error
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: currentBuild for class: Script1

Answer (score 3):

This will do the trick:

```
def url = scheduledJob.getFuture().waitForStart().getUrl()
```

If you need an absolute URL, prepend `Jenkins.instance.getRootUrl()` to that string.

Comment: Here is a `Future` implementation of Jenkins:
http://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/queue/FutureImpl.html

Might not be clear, but if you want to wait for finalization of the job:
`scheduledJob.getFuture().get();`